# How to figure out declaration for "for" statement

Tags: excel, vba

In my code i have a statement called

```
  For I = 1 To 200
    Range("C47").Value = Worksheets("HAZIDS").Cells(I + 5, 2).Value
    conscat = Range("F47")
    check2 = cons Like conscat
    check3 = cons Like "All"
```

When trying to run the code i get an error saying

> "For without next"

And i can't seem to figure out how to solve that.

I have tried looking up how others have solved this, and trying different next statements without luck.

```
  Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim I As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim before As String
Dim after As String
Dim cons As String
Dim conscat As String
Dim checks As String
Dim check2 As String
Dim check3 As String
Dim rowbefore As String
Dim columbefore As String
Dim rowafter As String
Dim columafter As String
Dim checkbefore As String
Dim checkafter As String
Dim Previouscellcontentbefore As Integer
Dim Previouscellcontentafter As Integer



Sheets("for calculations").Visible = True

cons = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Personnel; Environment; Assets; Reputation; All", Title:="Choose consequence (NB: Case sensitive)", Default:="All")
Worksheets("For calculations").Activate

Range("D37:I42").ClearContents
Range("L37:Q42").ClearContents
Range("C34").ClearContents

Select Case cons

    Case "All"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows all types of consequences"
    Case "Personnel"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows all types of Personnel consequences"
    Case "Environment"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Environmental consequences"
    Case "Asset"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Asset consequences"
    Case "Reputation"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Reputation consequences"
End Select


For I = 1 To 200
    Range("C47").Value = Worksheets("HAZIDS").Cells(I + 5, 2).Value
    conscat = Range("F47")
    check2 = cons Like conscat
    check3 = cons Like "All"

If cons Like "All" Then
    check2 = True
End If

    If check2 Then

before = Range("D47")
after = Range("E47")
rowbefore = Mid(before, 2, 1)
columbefore = Mid(before, 4, 1)
rowafter = Mid(after, 2, 1)
columafter = Mid(after, 4, 1)

checkbefore = Not rowbefore Like "" And Not columbefore Like ""
checkafter = Not rowafter Like "" And Not columafter Like ""

    If checkbefore Then
        Range("C36").Select
        Previouscellcontentbefore = ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowbefore) + 1, CInt(columbefore) + 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowbefore) + 1, CInt(columbefore) + 1) = Range("C47").Value & ", " & Previouscellcontentbefore

    If checkafter Then
        Range("K36").Select
        Previouscellcontentafter = ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowafter) + 1, CInt(columafter) + 1)
          ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowafter) + 1, CInt(columafter) + 1) = Range("C47").Value & ", " & Previouscellcontentafter

        End If
    End If
End If



End Sub
```

The code is supposed to check different ranges for specific inputs, and run the rest of the code with the input given in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the error says, you are missing a Next.

```
For I = 1 To 200 ' the code loops from here
    Range("C47").Value = Worksheets("HAZIDS").Cells(I + 5, 2).Value
    conscat = Range("F47")
    check2 = cons Like conscat
    check3 = cons Like "All"
Next I ' to here
```

Without the Next it doesn't know where the loop ends.